# Update shiny input based on datatable settings

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a leaflet map & datatable in a shiny app and have various input boxes to select what is being mapped.

Currently the data is processed on the server based on a set of shiny inputs, and that data is passed to both leaflet and datatable.
I'd also like to have a button on the datatable (or read double clicks on the datatable) and update a shiny input (i.e., call `shiny::updateSelectizeInput`) based on the users interaction with the datatable.

minimal code example:

```r
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(DT)
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      selectInput("species_selection", "Select species",
                  choices = c("all", as.character(iris$Species)))

      , dataTableOutput("dt")
      )
    , server = function(input, output) {

      output$dt <- renderDataTable({
        if ( input$species_selection != "all" ) {
        for_table <- iris %>%
          filter(Species == input$species_selection)
        } else {
          for_table <- iris
        }
        for_table
        # but also you can click a button or double-click a row on this datatable
        # to update input$species_selection above
      })
    }
  )
}
```

I'm aware there's no reason for this in this minimal example but I do want to do so for in the context of my larger app.
I've seen examples (for example, [superzip](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html)) where buttons on the datatable are linked to html, and I know the datatable shiny tutorials tell you how to catch selected rows with an observer. Catching the selected rows is my backup plan but I would prefer a button on the row or a double-click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, but its a bit fiddly. I used mtcars as it has more variety:

[image: input buttons in datatable]

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


shinyApp(

    #UI
    ui <- fluidPage(

        selectInput('carb_selection', 'Select carb', choices = c('all', as.character(mtcars$carb))),
        DT::dataTableOutput('dt'),

    ),

    #Server
    server <- function(input, output, session) {

        #Function to create buttons
        shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {

            inputs <- character(len)
            for (i in seq_len(len)) {
                inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
            }
            inputs

        }

        #Add buttons to the mtcars dataframe
        mtcars_btn <- reactiveValues(

            data = data.frame(

                mtcars,
                carb_selector = shinyInput(actionButton, nrow(mtcars), 'button_', label = "Select", onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\", this.id)'),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE

            )

        )

        #Output datatable
        output$dt <- DT::renderDataTable(

            if (input$carb_selection == 'all'){

                DT::datatable(mtcars_btn$data, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', options = list(searching = FALSE, ordering  = FALSE))

            } else {

                DT::datatable(mtcars_btn$data[mtcars_btn$data$carb == input$carb_selection, ], escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', options = list(searching = FALSE, ordering  = FALSE))

            }

        )

        #Observe a button being clicked
        observeEvent(input$select_button, {

            carb_selected <- mtcars_btn$data[as.numeric(strsplit(input$select_button, "_")[[1]][2]),]$carb

            print(paste0('clicked on ', carb_selected))

            updateSelectInput(session, 'carb_selection', selected = carb_selected)

        })

    }

)
```

Note that you may wish to switch between local and server processing when using large dataframes.